# How to copy one field data to another and save a new revision?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, hooks

We are going to remove an obsolete field(field_old) and will be using a new field (field_new) and have a need to copy the data from field_old to field_new (both text fields). Then we need to create a new revision of the node so that field_new can be saved moving forward.

Below is what we have tried but it is not working.

```
function mymodule_update_7001(&$sandox) {
   $result = db_select('node', 'n')
             ->fields('n', array('nid', 'field_old', 'field_new'))
             ->condition('n.type', 'article')
             ->execute()
             ->fetchAll();

   foreach( $result as $nd) {
        $node = node_load($nd->nid);
        $node->field_new = $node->field_old;
        $node->revision = TRUE;
        node_save($node);
   }
 }
```

Through the node/edit screen under URL Settings, i can check the "Auto generate URL alias" checkbox. How would i be able to incorporate as part of the field copy?

Comment: Are you using rules? You can create a rule for "node is updated", have an action to set set new data value with old and then use vbo to trigger the rule for all your nodes. The new revision should be created automatically. Not sure about the url alias though. I use pathauto for that.

Comment: @NiallMurphy What option would i set to set new data value with old data from another field? I could not see the option when i tried.

Comment: After adding your "updated" event, you need to expose the fields to rules by first using the "entity has field" condition. After that, action: set a data value. (Or for unlimited fields, loop and add to list). An sql query is good but rules and then vbo is the nice gui way.